# Multiply each element of a list by an entire other list

Tags: python, list, numpy, performance

I have two lists which are very large. The basic structure is :
`a = [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]` and `b=[1,0,1,0]`. There is no restriction on the length of either list and there is also no restriction on the value of the elements in either list.
I want to multiply each element of `a` by the contents of `b`.
For example, the following code does the job:

```
multiplied = []
for a_bit in a:
     for b_bit in b:
          multiplied.append(a_bit*b_bit)
```

So for the even simpler case of `a=[1,0]`  and `b = [1,0,1,0]`, the output `multiplied` would be equal to:

```
>>> print(multiplied)
[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Is there a way with `numpy` or `map` or `zip` to do this? There are similar questions that are multiplying lists with lists and a bunch of other variations but I haven't seen this one. The problem is that, my nested `for` loops above are fine and they work but they take forever to process on larger arrays.

Comment: What are you doing with the result? And are all values zeros and ones? And how large is "very large"?

Comment: @KellyBundy The first question is irrelevant. I have edited the question to answer the second. The third is merely answered in the fact that they are large enough to cause the amount of time to process via the mentioned way to be unacceptable.

Comment: A straight forward list comprehension: `[i*j for i in a for j in b]`.  If you actually start with arrays, then the array multiplication will be faster.  But if you start with lists, the act of creating arrays from the lists could cancel out any time savings.

Comment: @hpaulj They said the lists are very large, so creating the arrays is negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using matrix multiplication, and then flattening the result.

```
>>> a = np.array([1,0]).reshape(-1,1)
>>> b = np.array([1,0,1,0])
>>> a*b
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> (a*b).flatten()
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>>
```